# Set Angular RC 4 unit test with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular-universal

I'm coding a app with Angular Universal which obliges me to use Angular 2 RC 4 because Angular Universal is not compatible with RC5, yet.

I'm looking for the documentation of Angular 2 RC 4 to know the right way to use @angular/core/testing with webpack. Does anyone knows where I can find it? Or Does anyone have an example of Angular 2 RC4 + webpack + karma configuration?

Thank you